# SuiteScript 2.0 Add filters to saved search in script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a custom record that has a field for an item and a field for location. I have a saved search on that record that already has the columns I want and some beginning criteria that will always be needed. I want to use this search when I am on a Sales Order. I want to store an array of all the item internal ids and location ids on the lines and then pass that as a dynamic filter to this search in SuiteScript 2.0.

According to the documentation this can be done. On the search.Filter page it says "You create a search filter object with search.createFilter(options) and add it to a search.Search object that you create with search.create(options) or load with search.load(options)." However, I do not see any parameter on search.load for this nor a code example of adding it after the load. All examples of using search.Filter are in using it in the search.create function

Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can push the filter object to the filters property of the search.

```
searchObj.filters.push(filterObj);
```

Comment: search.createFilter({options}) can be used to create your filterObj

Comment: Very crisp.  I went away when it didn't work, and at the end found it was all I needed..  along with a bug report to Netsuite :).

Answer (score 6):

I will list the steps in a simple way so that you can understand it better.
After you get the hang of it,you can edit it the way you want

**STEPS :**

1.Load saved search (say **objSearch** )

2.Copy the filters from **objSearch** into a new array (say **defaultFilters** )

3.Create a new array (say **customFilters** ) to store the new filter and we push it into **defaultFilters**

4.At last, we copy the modified **defaultFilters** back into **objSearch** and run the saved search

```
//Load saved search into objSearch    
var objSearch = search.load({
                id: 'savedsearchid'
            });

//Copy the filters from objSearch into defaultFilters
            var defaultFilters = objSearch.filters;

            var customFilters = [];

            //We will add the new filter in customFilters
            customFilters = ['postingperiod', 'ANYOF', '1'];

//We will push the customFilters into defaultFilters
            defaultFilters.push(customFilters);


//We will copy the modified defaultFilters back into objSearch
     objSearch.filters = defaultFilters;


//Run the saved search
            var objSearch_run = objSearch.run().getRange({
                start: 0,
                end: 10
            });
```

Comment: I mentioned this in a post to a different answer (and linked to your answer here!), but you can concatenate the filter arrays together to make this a little simpler as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57732755/880695

Answer (score 0):

```
var mySearch = search.load({ id: '851' });
var defaultFilters = mySearch.filters;
var customFilters = {};
customFilters = {"name":"custrecord_customer","operator":"anyof","values":["64468"],"isor":false,"isnot":false,"leftparens":0,"rightparens":0};        
defaultFilters.push(customFilters);
mySearch.filters = defaultFilters;
```