# NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0 Adding additional filters to a loaded saved search erroring with WRONG_PARAMETER_TYPE

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have the following SuiteScript 2.0 code in a Suitelet where I would like to add an additional filter to the loaded saved search (inventory items sublist and main record of the Inventory Adjustment record):

```
  var rs = s.load({
    id: "customsearch_inv_adj_item_search"
  });

  // Copy the filters from rs into defaultFilters.
  var defaultFilters = rs.filters;
  var customFilters = [
     s.createFilter({
        name: "internalid",
        operator: s.Operator.IS,
        values: request.parameters.custscript_report_context.toString()
     }),
  ];

  // Push the customFilters into defaultFilters.
  defaultFilters.push(customFilters);

  // Copy the modified defaultFilters back into rs
  rs.filters = defaultFilters;

  var results = rs.run().getRange(0, 1000);
```

However the code keeps on failing on the line `rs.filters = defaultFilters;` with the error:

```
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"WRONG_PARAMETER_TYPE","message":"Wrong parameter type: filters[2] is expected as Filter. ","stack":["createError(N/error)","onRequest(/SuiteScripts/sui_custom_pdf_report.js:308)","createError(N/error)"],"cause":{"name":"WRONG_PARAMETER_TYPE","message":"Wrong parameter type: filters[2] is expected as Filter. "},"id":"","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":true}
```

Instead of `request.parameters.custscript_report_context.toString()` I have tried `981, "981", ["981"]` but no luck.

`custscript_report_context` is of type integer and it works fine in trying to load the record via `N\record`.

I am returning `internalid` in my saved search as a column.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot push an array in **searchFilters**, only filter objects. Arrays are required if you use **filter-expressions**.

Try the following code

```
var rs = s.load({
  id: "customsearch_inv_adj_item_search"
});

// Copy the filters from rs into defaultFilters.
var defaultFilters = rs.filters;

// Push the customFilters into defaultFilters.

defaultFilters.push(s.createFilter({
  name: "internalid",
  operator: s.Operator.IS,
  values: request.parameters.custscript_report_context.toString()
}));
// Copy the modified defaultFilters back into rs
rs.filters = defaultFilters;

var results = rs.run().getRange(0, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks dude, you're a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other answers...while you can't push an array as mentioned in @Avi 's answer, you can **concatenate** the arrays as such, eliminating the need to loop through them. This is kind of drawn out, just to show the concept:

```
 var additionalFilters = new Array();;
                 additionalFilters.push(search.createFilter({name: 'account', operator: search.Operator.ANYOF, values: mainArgs.
                 additionalFilters.push(search.createFilter({name: 'postingperiod', operator: search.Operator.IS, values:[mainArgs.param_posting_period]}));

                 var mySearch = search.load({id: searchID});
                 if(additionalFilters){

                     //Copy the filters from mySearch into defaultFilters
                     var defaultFilters = mySearch.filters;

                     //We will add the new filter in customFilters
                     var customFilters = [];
                     customFilters = additionalFilters;

                     //We will concatenate the customFilters and defaultFilters, thereby creating a new array called allFilters
                     var allFilters = defaultFilters.concat(customFilters);

                     //We will assign the allFilters array back into mySearch
                     mySearch.filters = allFilters;

                 }
```

Note: This is an edited version of what I gleaned from a different [post / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47791756)